# How to sum the values of a series into a dataframe based on a mask numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following variables:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

y = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
mask_y = np.array([[True, False, False], [False, False, True], [False, False, False]])
dist_y = pd.Series([0.222, 0.333, 0.444])
```

I need to add the values of `dist_y` into `y` using the `mask_y` `True` values as condition. I expect to get:

```
       A  B      C
0  1.222  2  3.000
1  4.000  5  6.333
2  7.000  8  9.000
```

I have tried the following:

```
y.loc[:, mask_y] += dist_y.values[:, None]
```

But this does not work. Any ideas how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the `y` with broadcasted `dist_y` then conditionally assign the result back

```py
y[mask_y] = y + dist_y.values[:, None]
```

```
$ print(y)

       A  B      C
0  1.222  2  3.000
1  4.000  5  6.333
2  7.000  8  9.000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame as df
import inspect


df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
"""
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
"""
mask_df = np.array([[True, False, False], [False, False, True], [False, False, False]])
dist_df = pd.Series([0.222, 0.333, 0.444])



"""
Requirement :

Add the values of dist_df into df using the mask_df True values as condition.
 
""" 
res = df.mask(mask_df, df.add(dist_df, axis=0))
print (res)

"""
       A  B      C
0  1.222  2  3.000
1  4.000  5  6.333
2  7.000  8  9.000

"""
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying a bit of [Ynjxsjmh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75722230/21319172) you can get some efficiency improvements.

```py
y = mask_y * dist_y.values[None, :].T + y
```